# How to open a link into same tab when click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a link into same tab when I click a submit button. I try window.location.href="form.h". But is not working..

```
<div id="advanced-search" class="form-group form-action col-md-12"        
  <button type="submit" class="btn-search btn btn-flat-alizarin" onclick = 
  window.location.href="form.html";>Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Code does work.  See if you don't have popup blocker loaded.  Also, on IE, it complained about active content.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `button type="submit"` try `button type="button"` and check the closing tags of div and use quotes in `onclick` handler as well.

Comment: @neelabhsingh...happy to help you..do upvote accept the answer if it helped you..

Comment: @neelabhsingh...No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Look like you missed the closing tag for div..
Try this..

```
<div id="advanced-search" class="form-group form-action col-md-12">
<button type="submit" class="btn-search btn btn-flat-alizarin" onclick='window.location.href="form.html"'>Search</button></div>
```